# Swift Playground Stopped Evaluating

Tags: swift, xcode6

I was playing around with the Swift GuidedTour.playground when it stopped showing the evaluation of variables. How can I turn this back on ?

It works when I create a new playground. I must have pushed some button to turn this off but cannot turn it back on

[image]

This is the same code on a new playground with evaluations

[image]

Comment: OK I have resolved this, I had an error far down the page. It does not evaluate from the top.

Comment: Sometimes it just stops evaluating. Adding a new line (for example) and the evaluations show up again.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried to use **Reset PlayGround** in Editor menu?

[image]

And if you have **error in code**, live coding may not work. Always **check the console** after changing your code.

Comment: I had not seen that, I did resolve it though by fixing an error at the bottom of the tutorial. I will see if that reset also works

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, if you have an error it will stop evaluating  your code , so fix asn save the file and it will start doing it again